# Refrence of hadith?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

I am trying to find on google and specially on sunnah.com
Is there any hadith whose approximate meaning is as follow:

"O ye
pepple who have professed Islam as mere exercise of the
tongue and belief has not gone to your hearts {not become a
strong conviction), do not cause distress to Muslims (injuring
their feelings), nor put them to shame, nor be after fault-finding
with them. Those who pursue others doggedly seeking their
faults Allah shall pursue their faults. And whom Allah pursues
for their faults, He will bring them to ignominy, even if they
remain hidden in their houses"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been recorded by Tirmidhi ([2032](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2032) ) and Abu Dawud ([4880](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4880)) among the six books, and also by several others.